# Как вывести массив на экран С++?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

```
float a[3][3] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1) {
        printf("Введите элемент массиваn");
        scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("%fn", a[i][j]);
}

getchar();
```

До последнего printf все идет без ошибок, но потом выдает ошибку и на экран массив не выводится.

Comment: @ek8800, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Внесите printf внутрь границ цикла, иначе индексы либо не определены, либо выходят за границы массива.

Comment: Внес, безуспешно. Выдает ошибку, а где она понять не могу

Answer (score 2):

В scanf() передавайте адрес элемента массива

```
float a[3][3];
...
scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
```

Во внутреннем цикле надо не i < 3, а j < 3 (сейчас Вы пробегаете индексы [0][0], [0][1, [0][2], [0][3] ... [0][много - свалились])

В последнем printf() i и j вне границ Вашего массива.

**UPDATE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  float a[2][2];
  int i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf ("[%d][%d] > ",i,j); 
      fflush(stdout);
      if (scanf ("%f",&a[i][j]) != 1) {
        printf ("error reading a[%d][%d]\n",i,j);
        j -= 2;
        if (j< 0)
          j = -1;
        char buf[100];
        fgets(buf,100,stdin);
        printf ("try to enter again\n");
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf ("%f ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }

}
```

Что непонятно, задавайте вопросы (только конкретно).

Comment: Посмотри я исправил. Но все равно не проходит. Мне кажется я ошибаюсь в строке вывода "prinf("%f\n", a[i][j]); "

Comment: float оставьте, как есть (я убрал double в ответе).

В printf() у Вас j == 3, т.е. вне границ массива.

Вы просто введите scanf()-ом во вложенных циклах, а потом в других распечатайте:

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf ("a[%d][%d] = %f ",i,j,a[i][j]);
        printf ("\\n");
    }

Comment: Я в этом языке не больше не меньше, а два дня. Если често я не совсем понял что Вы мне попытались объяснить. Исправив свой код на данный у меня ничего хорошего не вышло. Все по прежнему выдает ошибку. Где тут ввод данных получается и где scanf?

Comment: @ek8800, зачем Вы 2 одинаковых вопроса с чуть разными заголовками задаете ?

Сейча в **UPDATE** ответа кину код.

Comment: Ну я извинился в следующем посту за это) Просто хочу двигаться вперед, а тут с выводом массива какая то проблема.

Comment: Сейчас буду смотреть. Вот ты мне бомбу на голову скмнул, думаю к утру разберусь). 
Спасибо, еще думаю напишу тебе и не один раз)

Answer (score 1):

Вам тут уже ответили на вопрос, сделаю небольшое замечание. Для ввода и вывода лучше используйте:

```
std::cin
std::cout
```

Вы должны понимать, что функции `scanf/printf` относятся к языку C, а `std::cin/std::cout` - к языку С++. Ваш вопрос касается C++, судя по заголовку.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ...
cout << "Enter value: ";
cin >> a[i][j];
// ...
```

Comment: Я использую Visual Studio тут я как понял
printf=cout
scanf=cin

Мне в таком формате нужно писать

Comment: Нет. Можно и так, и так. Обратитесь к стандарту языка.

Comment: Я уже просто весь день мужусь с printf и scanf/
Хоелось бы при помощи них научиться.
Я програмный код немного исправил посмотри может увидишь в чем ошибка.
При помощи cout & cin в CodeBlocks все получается.